# Android gradle configure java 1.8

Tags: java, android, gradle

I am trying to configure Gradle with the java plugin for an Android project. The project consists on an Android library and Android application. The application uses the library to perform some operations. This is my gradle file for the application:

```
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'com.android.model.application'

model {
    android {
        compileSdkVersion 27
        buildToolsVersion "27.0.2"
        defaultConfig{
            applicationId "xxxxxxxxx"
            minSdkVersion.apiLevel 19
            targetSdkVersion.apiLevel 27
            versionCode 1
            versionName "0.1"

            testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
            multiDexEnabled true
        }
        buildTypes {
            release {
                minifyEnabled false
                proguardFiles.add(file("proguard-rules.pro"))
            }
        }
    }
    compileJava{
        sourceCompatilibity = 1.8
        targetCompatibility = 1.8
    }
}


repositories {
    jcenter()
    maven {
        url 'https://maven.google.com'
    }
    flatDir {
        dirs 'libs'
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])

    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile project(path: ':my_library')

    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'

}
```

The error displayed in the gradle compilation is the following:

> Cannot create 'tasks.test' using creation rule
>   'BaseComponentModelPlugin.Rules#createRemainingTasks(ModelMap,
>   TaskManager, ModelMap) > create(test)' as the
>   rule 'Project..tasks.test()' is already registered to create
>   this model element.

I have read that including java plugin in Gradle automatically adds a test task, I would remove it but I need to use Java 1.8 to compile the project. Any help/tip about this error would be highly appreciated, thanks.

**UPDATE:**
Finally I managed to configure the project. Since it was mandatory for me to use gradle-experimental (I am using an NDK dependency that requires it), my only choice was to upgrade the minimum API level to 26 and remove the Java 1.8 compatibility, this is my final build.gradle file:

```
    apply plugin: 'com.android.model.application'

model {
    android {
        compileSdkVersion = 27
        buildToolsVersion = "27.0.2"
        defaultConfig.with {
            applicationId = "xxxxxxxxxx"
            minSdkVersion.apiLevel = 26
            targetSdkVersion.apiLevel = 27
            versionCode = 1
            versionName  = "0.1"

            testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
            multiDexEnabled true
        }
        buildTypes {
            release {
                minifyEnabled false
                proguardFiles.add(file('proguard-android.txt'))
            }
        }
    }
}

repositories {
    jcenter()
    google()
    flatDir {
        dirs 'libs'
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])

    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile project(path: ':my-library')
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.0.2'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:27.0.2'

    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'

    // Brings the new BluetoothLeScanner API to older platforms
    compile 'no.nordicsemi.android.support.v18:scanner:1.1.0'

    // BLE library
    compile 'no.nordicsemi.android:ble:1.2.0'
}
```